# how to detect the users timezone by the browser (google, etc) using python

Tags: python

```
country_time_zone = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
time_details = datetime.now(country_time_zone).time()
```

with this piece of code i can get only in NEW YORK, also if i do this

```
print(pytz.all_timezones_set)
```

i would get all the names of the times zones in the world, the continent + the country

although i want to detect the users timezone, so if an user is in USA, it shows the hour of the USA, if the user is in Europe then it shows the hour of the europe and so on

Comment: User of what? Is this meant to be a web app, script, or? When you say "navigator", maybe you mean "browser"? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @anonymuus_gp, are you trying to build a web app? If so, you can send the local time from the front-end to the back-end.

Comment: The question is not clear. A region or country can have multiple time zones. Could you explain in more detail what you mean?

Comment: It looks like you'd need to run Javascript in the browser to get the TZ and then tell your Python script.  I don't think there's anything in HTTP, for example, that tells you the users time zone.

Comment: @Max are you sure? is there not a way to get it only with the backend using a function?

Comment: @Vitalizzare i want to obtain the timezone of the location of an user, when the person  checks in the app

Comment: I mean, you could try to geolocate the IP of the user, but that's going to be error prone, but as far as I know there's no Client HTTP header that gives the user's Time Zone.

Comment: I noticed you put some explanation in your edit summary, but people don't see that unless they go looking for it, so you might want to [edit] and add it in to the question itself.